# Swift and Physics Body

Tags: swift

In Swift, how do you make a custom physicsBody Shape. For example, there are only limited shapes you can use like rectangle and circle. However, I want to know what to do if you have a complex shape.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try CAShapeLayer which has a path property